Gracefully prevent SwiftData from deleting values that are a part of the NavigationPath
I have views from which I can navigate very freely, and my navigation path could look like this:
Route(0)/Route(3)/Route(4)/Route(10)/Route(4)
Besides navigating freely, I can delete any route from a route view. However, when I delete entries in SwiftData referenced in the path, I get strange behaviors. Either they don't get deleted, or the screen freezes when I navigate back to an entry I've deleted.
I want to show a toast like "You can't delete routes from which you navigated through" or allow me to delete a part of the path but "jump over" deleted paths when I navigate back in the hierarchy.
PS: In the actual code, I use more than one type for navigation, so I can't just use a [Route] and check if the path includes the route I'm trying to delete.
I'm unsure if this code helps understand the problem. Consider it a sudo code example to add some context, but it might differentiate from my description above.
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ExploreDeletingPartOfNavigationPath: View {
    @State private var pathWrapper = NavigationPathWrapper()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $pathWrapper.path) {
            Text("Go to: 1")
                .onTapGesture {
                    pathWrapper.path.append(Route(number: 1))
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Route.self) { route in
                    RouteView(route: route)
                }
        }
        .environment(pathWrapper)
        .modelContainer(for: Route.self)
    }
}

struct RouteView: View {
    @Environment(NavigationPathWrapper.self) var pathWrapper
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var context
    let route: Route
    var body: some View {
        let nextRouteNumber = route.number + 1
        Text("Go to: \(nextRouteNumber)")
            .onTapGesture {
                pathWrapper.path.append(Route(number: nextRouteNumber))
            }
        Text("Delete random route")
            .onTapGesture {
                context.delete(Route(number: Int.random(in: 1..<pathWrapper.path.count)))
            }
    }
}

@Model
class Route: Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let number: Int

    init(number: Int) {
        self.number = number
    }
}

@Observable
class NavigationPathWrapper {
    var path = NavigationPath()
}

#Preview {
    ExploreDeletingPartOfNavigationPath()
}

